# Is passing activity context to a function without storing it safe?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know storing activity context, for example passing it in a constructor to a ViewModel, is bad practice.

However, if I have a function in my ViewModel or other non lifecycle-aware class that takes context as a parameter without storing it at the class level, does this remove the potential for memory leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question, **Yes**! Having `context` as parameter does not have any potential leak if you are not storing it in class level given you don't use the `context` in some background task. The function parameters are short lived and would not hold any references after execution is complete.

But, passing `context` to `ViewModel` has other problems, it is always better to avoid using android components either in constructor/methods or in any form inside `Viewmodel` to decouple it from android framework dependency and hence helps in unit testing in isolated java environment!

Answer (score -1):

Also, you could do things like getting the views that are shown in an activity by doing

```
View v = ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.viewId);
```

These view references should not be stored either otherwise that can cause leaks too.